# How can I access pixels from 1,2,4 bpp images?

Tags: c#, image, pixel, bitmapsource

I have a working code that can access a determined pixel value if the given image has 8, 24 or 32bpp. Here's is the code:

Using a `BitmapSource`:

```
// Get width and height of bitmap
Width = _source.PixelWidth;
Height = _source.PixelHeight;

// Get total locked pixels count
int pixelCount = Width * Height;

// Get source bitmap pixel format size
Depth = _source.Format.BitsPerPixel;

// Create byte array to copy pixel values
int step = Depth / 8;
Pixels = new byte[pixelCount * step];
_iptr = _data.BackBuffer;

// Copy data from pointer to array
Marshal.Copy(_iptr, Pixels, 0, Pixels.Length);

int count = Depth / 8;

if (count == 0)
    count = 1;

//Get start index of the specified pixel
int i = ((y * Width) + x) * count;

if (i > Pixels.Length - count)
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

if (Depth == 32) //For 32 bpp get Red, Green, Blue and Alpha
{
    byte b = Pixels[i];
    byte g = Pixels[i + 1];
    byte r = Pixels[i + 2];
    byte a = Pixels[i + 3]; // a
    clr = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
}
else if (Depth == 24) //For 24 bpp get Red, Green and Blue
{
    byte b = Pixels[i];
    byte g = Pixels[i + 1];
    byte r = Pixels[i + 2];
    clr = Color.FromRgb(r, g, b);
}
else if (Depth == 8) //For 8 bpp get color value (Red, Green and Blue values are the same)
{
    byte c = Pixels[i];
    clr = Color.FromRgb(c, c, c);
}
```

And to set the pixel value:

```
if (Depth == 32) //For 32 bpp set Red, Green, Blue and Alpha
{
    Pixels[i] = color.B;
    Pixels[i + 1] = color.G;
    Pixels[i + 2] = color.R;
    Pixels[i + 3] = color.A;
}
else if (Depth == 24) //For 24 bpp set Red, Green and Blue
{
    Pixels[i] = color.B;
    Pixels[i + 1] = color.G;
    Pixels[i + 2] = color.R;
}
else if (Depth == 8) //For 8 bpp set color value (Red, Green and Blue values are the same)
{
    Pixels[i] = color.B;
}
```

So, how can I access (get,set) 1,2 or 4bpp pixel values?

Comment: Just throw an exception.  These pixel formats became obsolete 20 years ago.  Good riddance, palettes were a major pita.  Throw for 8bpp as well so your incorrect code can't do any damage.

Comment: And still I got a 4bpp image, the question is not *How should I face 1,2,4 and 8bpp images?*, but **How can I proceed to get the pixels and do something else with that image?**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently converting the image to some other `Format` before trying to read the pixel values. That solves my problem.